# New line in ToolTip for ASP.NET from SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip

I have some ToolTips for ASP.NET controls stored in my SQL Server database. As they are quite long, I'm using a new line character (\n), it works fine in MS Edge (and I think it worked fine in IE), but it doesn't work in Google Chrome and some other browsers (Opera, etc.) - it doesn't break line and shows \n instead.

IF I use the very same text in my code behind - e.g. myControl.ToolTip = "one line\nanotherline" - then it works fine and shows two line in Google Chrome and everywhere. But if I pull it from the database, it will show one line with \n in the middle :( - I tried adding \r as well to no avail.

Would appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. It was not actually working for Edge either - it was just breaking itself roughly at the places where I wanted it to break and in Google Chrome it was all just one long line, hence some confusion.

The issue was that new line character (\n) is returned from the database with an extra backslash, but it's not shown when displayed. So in the database it's \n, but it returns \n. So I added the following code and it works fine now:

```
myControl.ToolTip = myObject.DescriptionFromDB.Replace( "\\n", "\n" );
```